# How to tranpose data in listview vertically

Tags: listview, csv, vb6

I am a beginner in VB6. My project right now is to parse a raw data and get only the needed data and save it as CSV file. I can already parse the raw and viewed in list view my problem is the data will inputted horizontally in listview and when i viewed it in CSV file the is same as the listview.

My question now is how can i put the data in listview `vertically` while i parse the data?

below is the output in listview after parsing data

[image]

This is my code to put the data in listview

```
If cmd_req_flow <> "" And cmd_req_flow_a <> "" Then
                                txt_date = cmd_date_time_a
                                txt_parsereq = cmd_totalparsedreq_a - cmd_totalparsedreq
                                txt_flowtotal = cmd_flow_total_a
                                txt_reqflow = cmd_req_flow_a
                                txt_aia = cmd_aia_a - cmd_aia
                                txt_air = cmd_air_a - cmd_air
                                txt_cer = cmd_cer_a - cmd_cer
                                txt_cla = cmd_cla_a - cmd_cla
                                txt_clr = cmd_clr_a - cmd_clr
                                txt_dsa = cmd_dsa_a - cmd_dsa
                                txt_dsr = cmd_dsr_a - cmd_dsr
                                txt_dwa = cmd_dwa_a - cmd_dwa
                                txt_dwr = cmd_dwr_a - cmd_dwr
                                txt_ida = cmd_ida_a - cmd_ida
                                txt_idr = cmd_idr_a - cmd_idr
                                txt_noa = cmd_noa_a - cmd_noa
                                txt_nor = cmd_nor_a - cmd_nor
                                txt_pua = cmd_pua_a - cmd_pua
                                txt_pur = cmd_pur_a - cmd_pur
                                txt_rsa = cmd_rsa_a - cmd_rsa
                                txt_rsr = cmd_rsr_a - cmd_rsr
                                txt_ula = cmd_ula_a - cmd_ula
                                txt_ulr = cmd_ulr_a - cmd_ulr

                                     Set itmX = ListView1.ListItems.Add(, , txt_date)
                                                itmX.SubItems(1) = txt_parsereq
                                                itmX.SubItems(2) = txt_flowtotal
                                                itmX.SubItems(3) = txt_reqflow
                                                itmX.SubItems(4) = txt_aia
                                                itmX.SubItems(5) = txt_air
                                                itmX.SubItems(6) = txt_cer
                                                itmX.SubItems(7) = txt_cla
                                                itmX.SubItems(8) = txt_clr
                                                itmX.SubItems(9) = txt_dsa
                                                itmX.SubItems(10) = txt_dsr
                                                itmX.SubItems(11) = txt_dwa
                                                itmX.SubItems(12) = txt_dwr
                                                itmX.SubItems(13) = txt_ida
                                                itmX.SubItems(14) = txt_idr
                                                itmX.SubItems(15) = txt_noa
                                                itmX.SubItems(16) = txt_nor
                                                itmX.SubItems(17) = txt_pua
                                                itmX.SubItems(18) = txt_pur
                                                itmX.SubItems(19) = txt_rsa
                                                itmX.SubItems(20) = txt_rsr
                                                itmX.SubItems(21) = txt_ula
                                                itmX.SubItems(22) = txt_ulr
                                        Call clear_fourth
                                        Call clear_five
                                        Call clear_first

                                        Call clear_field_name
                                        Call clear_value
                                        txt_sec = 0
                                        txt_t1 = ""
                                        txt_t2 = ""
                                        txt_st = ""

                                               cmd_date_time = cmd_date_time_a
                                               cmd_ulr = cmd_ulr_a
                                               cmd_aia = cmd_aia_a
                                               cmd_dsa = cmd_dsa_a
                                               cmd_rsr = cmd_rsr_a
                                               cmd_dsr = cmd_dsr_a
                                               cmd_noa = cmd_noa_a
                                               cmd_pur = cmd_pur_a
                                               cmd_dwa = cmd_dwa_a
                                               cmd_clr = cmd_clr_a
                                               cmd_cla = cmd_cla_a
                                               cmd_nor = cmd_nor_a
                                               cmd_pua = cmd_pua_a
                                               cmd_totalparsedreq = cmd_totalparsedreq_a
                                               cmd_rsa = cmd_rsa_a
                                               cmd_air = cmd_air_a
                                               cmd_ida = cmd_ida_a
                                               cmd_ula = cmd_ula_a
                                               cmd_cer = cmd_cer_a
                                               cmd_flow_total = cmd_flow_total_a
                                               cmd_idr = cmd_idr_a
                                               cmd_dwr = cmd_dwr_a
                                               cmd_req_flow = cmd_req_flow_a
                                        Call clear_second
                            End If
```

Comment: i need to get the data vertically not horizontally.

Comment: why dont you use a grid control like the flexgrid control? it makes it much easier to address specific cells and loop through the cells either per column or per row

Comment: can you give me example for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to add a msflexgrid control to your form you first have to add the component which you can do in the menu.

In the **project** menu click on **components** and in there check the **microsoft flexGrid control**

Then have a look at the following test project:

```
'1 form with:
'  MSFlexGrid: name=MSFlexGrid1
'  Command button: name=Command1
Option Explicit

Private Sub Command1_Click()
  Static lngMode As Long
  'process the right modes
  Select Case lngMode
    Case 0
      FillHorizontal
    Case 1
      FillVertical
    Case 2
      FillData
  End Select
  'set next mode
  lngMode = (lngMode + 1) Mod 3
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
  With MSFlexGrid1
    .FixedRows = 0
    .FixedCols = 0
    .Rows = 7
    .Cols = 12
  End With 'MSFlexGrid1
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Resize()
  Dim sngWidth As Single, sngHeight As Single
  Dim sngCmdHeight As Single, sngGrdHeight As Single
  sngWidth = ScaleWidth
  sngHeight = ScaleHeight
  sngCmdHeight = 495
  sngGrdHeight = sngHeight - sngCmdHeight
  MSFlexGrid1.Move 0, 0, sngWidth, sngGrdHeight
  Command1.Move 0, sngGrdHeight, sngWidth, sngCmdHeight
End Sub

Private Sub FillHorizontal()
  Dim lngRow As Long, lngCol As Long
  With MSFlexGrid1
    For lngCol = 0 To .Cols - 1
      For lngRow = 0 To .Rows - 1
        .TextMatrix(lngRow, lngCol) = CStr(lngRow * .Cols + lngCol)
      Next lngRow
    Next lngCol
  End With 'MSFlexGrid1
End Sub

Private Sub FillVertical()
  Dim lngRow As Long, lngCol As Long
  With MSFlexGrid1
    For lngCol = 0 To .Cols - 1
      For lngRow = 0 To .Rows - 1
        .TextMatrix(lngRow, lngCol) = CStr(lngCol * .Rows + lngRow)
      Next lngRow
    Next lngCol
  End With 'MSFlexGrid1
End Sub

Private Sub FillData()
  With MSFlexGrid1
    .Clear
    .TextMatrix(0, 0) = "Food"
    .TextMatrix(0, 1) = "Drinks"
    .TextMatrix(1, 0) = "Cake"
    .TextMatrix(1, 1) = "Water"
    .TextMatrix(2, 0) = "Cup cake"
    .TextMatrix(2, 1) = "Soft drinks"
    .TextMatrix(3, 0) = "Spaghetti"
    .TextMatrix(3, 1) = "Orange juice"
    .TextMatrix(4, 0) = "Canton"
    .TextMatrix(4, 1) = "Coffee"
    .TextMatrix(5, 0) = "Abodo"
    .TextMatrix(5, 1) = "Tea"
  End With 'MSFlexGrid1
End Sub
```

When you click the button it will first fill the grid horizontally, when you click the button again it will fill the grid vertically, and when you click the button again it will fill the grid with some data

Pay attention to the use of lngRow and lngCol and how it effects the horizontal of vertical filling

Comment: the problem with MSFlexgrid is it cannot handle large amount of data.