# How to fill the 2nd column of ListView in VB6

Tags: listview, vb6

How can I fill the `2nd column` of `ListView` **without** filling the `1st column`? I am using `VB6`. Please give me a sample running code :) thank you.

Comment: why are you using a ListView? all questions from you could be a LOT easier be solved using a FlexGrid control instead of a ListView control

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the FlexGrid control instead of a ListView control.

I posted a [a small example project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22761761/1584106) in another post.

Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22761761/1584106